# How to wait for completion of Firestore indexes deployment more elegantly

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, continuous-integration, database-indexes

The problem with deploying Firestore indexes is that they are [long running operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#index_build_time).  That means that a deployment call already returns, before all indexes have been updated (see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase#continuous_deployment)). For example, when using Google Cloud Build:

```
- name: gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/firebase
  args: ['deploy', '--project=${PROJECT_ID}', '--only=firestore:indexes']
```

How do I wait for completion in my CI/CD build script? I have another successive step in the build script that migrates Firestore data, but that is dependent on successful complement of this indexes updating step.

One way is to poll for completion, using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#listing_all_long-running_operations) command

```
gcloud firestore operations list
```

and check whether there is any operation of type `type.googleapis.com/google.firestore.admin.v1.IndexOperationMetadata` running

However, this seems tricky and error prone. Does anyone know a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one gcloud command to check the status of the operation as mentioned in the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#check_operation_status).

```
Command :   gcloud firestore operations describe operation-name
```

In order to filter out the particular operations that are done, you can use the filters accordingly as stated in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/operations/list):

```
command : gcloud firestore operations list --filter="done:true"
```

You could write a bash script to iteratively check the index completion status and not exit until complete. When an operation is done, the operation description will contain "done": true. Note that the workEstimated value is only an estimate and cannot be used to accurately predict how long the operation will take. This method will also have to take into account Cloud Build [timeout values](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#timeout), as these index build times can be long.

Alternatively, you can also use the “[waitFor](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/configure-build-step-order)” condition in the next successive cloud build step to run after successful completion of the first cloud step, as in below example : -

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  args: ['install', 'mytarget']
  id: 'go-install'

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mytarget', '.']
  waitFor: ['go-install']
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I saw the 'operations describe', but do not know how to get the 'operation-name' unless if I parse the 'gcloud firestore operations list' result', but that kind of beats the purpose of it, Do you know if gcloud somehow returns this 'operation-name' after deploying the indexes? I do not see it

Comment: seems like this is the best that can be done for now. marked it as the correct one for now. hopefully better solutions will be implemented by google in future